# How to hide a component with ng-if when a button in another component is clicked in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components

I have two children components sitting in a parent component. I want to hide component1 when a button in component2 is clicked.

Here is a representation of the current code I am working with:

Parent Component HTML:

```
<div ng-app='app'>
<component1></component1>
<component2></component2>
</div>
```

Component1.js

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module('component1', [])
    .component('component1', {
        templateUrl: 'app/component1/component1.html',
        controller: [
            '$scope', '$timeout', '$element', '$location',
            function Component1Controller($scope, $timeout, $element, $location) {
                var my = this;

            }
        ]
    });
})();
```

Component1.html

```
<div ng-if="hideComponent" class="container-fluid">
<div class="animated fadeIn">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            Hide me!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Component2.js

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module('component2', [])
    .component('component2', {
        templateUrl: 'app/component2/component2.html',
        controller: [
            '$scope', '$timeout', '$element', '$location',
            function Component2Controller($scope, $timeout, $element, $location) {
                var my = this;
                var hideComponent = false;
                hideComponent = $scope.hideComponent;
            }
        ]
    });
})();
```

Component2.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="animated fadeIn">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button type="submit" ng-click="hideComponent(true)"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know there are ways to pass data, but when I google it, I either get information about Angular2, or it is about passing data from a child to a component, not a child to a child. I also understand you can use Services, but I want to use one of AngularJS binding methods, I have just not found a clear example for this use case so far.

Comment: Read [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based Application Architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture). If you wish to make the migration path to Angular 2+ easier, avoid using `$scope` and its event bus. Avoid using `$broadcast`, `$emit`, and `$on`.

Comment: So what you're saying is that soon AngularJS will fall off and a migration will be required? Thank you for your patience. So what I understand is that I should be using the one/two-way data binding instead of the event bus to pass data between components based on the document you referred to. I have looked at the Dev guide, but there are so many different ways to pass data in AngularJS it is hard for me to tell which is the best way moving forward.

Comment: AngularJS is scheduled for End-of-Life July 2021. For more information, see [AngularJS Version Support Status](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/version-support-status). See also [Angular Blog -- Stable AngularJS and Long Term Support](https://blog.angular.io/stable-angularjs-and-long-term-support-7e077635ee9c).  **An application is a tree of components:** Ideally, the whole application should be a tree of components that implement clearly defined inputs and outputs, and **minimize two-way data binding.** That way, it's easier to predict when data changes and what the state of a component is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way without using a service is to use a wrapper component that purely contains the others, in the controller of this component you can define a variable to do what you want and pass it using two way binding to the children.

The children can then change it on click and due to its two way binding behaviour changes will be propagated to the parent and to the sibling nodes

Comment: I don't understand how a wrapper component over the two children would be that different than the existing parent component. Would you mind explaining this difference?

Comment: Not really a difference, although if your parent component is something like a div you will have to ‘access’ a global scope to read/set the variable. This is not the cleanest approach as it doesn’t provide a good “business layer” between components.

Comment: The parent component is a div, so I should be able to perform what you explained. So I just need to define the "hideComponent" variable in the parent component, then bind it to each child component. The value would be a boolean and I believe it would be one-directional binding. But I don't understand quite how I would trigger the change to that value in one component, and then reflect that value change in the directive of another component.

Comment: It would be bidirectional because both children will update and receive updates through the parent scope. You’d simple access the parent scope and define such variables if you don’t want to do injections manually, or using broadcast.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the answer I was looking for using this article here:

http://dfsq.info/site/read/angular-components-communication

The main problem I was coming across was the developer before me chose the component-based architecture for this AngularJS application instead of the standard AngularJS architecture. This made it difficult to find the answer I was looking for while keeping the same Architecture and methods consistent in this application (I am on a deadline and have no time to re-factor). I knew I did not want to use Broadcast/Emit (forward thinking) and I did not want to use $rootScope (bad practice). I ended up using data binding as described in this article in order to pass data from a child component to another child component instead of child to parent to child again. Thank you for all who contributed and I hope this helps someone else with the same question because this problem has been consistent in my application.